# NSPredicate of multidimensional NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, nsnumber

Given is an NSArray with objects, each of which has an NSArray with floats, stored as NSNumbers.

I am trying to create an NSPredicate to filter my main array based on the float values. So, for instance, how to get all objects that have the value 234.6 +/- 0.8 as one of the floats in the sub-array?

I can do something like this for a one-dimensional NSArray of floats:

```
float targetFloat = 234.6;
float delta = 0.8;

filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"myFloat > %f AND myFloat < %f", (targetFloat - delta),  (targetFloat + delta)];
filteredArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filterPredicate];
```

But how do I change it for my 2D NSArray with NSNumbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate can access the object's property that holds the array by name; I've called this `list` in the example below. Then use the `ANY` keyword to check all the values in the array, and `BETWEEN` to find out if those values are within your chosen range.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Grumolo : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray * list;
@end

@implementation Grumolo
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %p, list: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self, [self list]];
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        float target = 234;
        float delta = 0.8;
        NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY list BETWEEN %@", @[@(target-delta), @(target+delta)]];

        NSArray * yes = @[@234, @10, @100];
        NSArray * yes2 = @[@0, @16, @234];
        NSArray * no = @[@1, @2, @3];

        Grumolo * g1 = [Grumolo new];
        [g1 setList:yes];
        Grumolo * g2  = [Grumolo new];
        [g2 setList:yes2];
        Grumolo * g3 = [Grumolo new];
        [g3 setList:no];


        NSLog(@"%@", [@[g1, g2, g3] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p]);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

You might also like to try `predicateWithBlock:`, which would let you express what you're trying to do with a traditional loop over each array, returning `YES` if you find an element that meets your criteria and `NO` if you exhaust the list.

```
NSPredicate * pb = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Grumolo * evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSArray * list = [evaluatedObject list];
        __block BOOL result = NO;
        [list enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            BOOL moreThanLower = (NSOrderedDescending == [obj compare:@(target-delta)]);
            BOOL lessThanUpper = (NSOrderedAscending == [obj compare:@(target+delta)]);
            if( moreThanLower && lessThanUpper ){
                *stop = YES;
                result = YES;
                return;
            }
        }];

        return result;
    }];
```

Comment: The "ANY list BETWEEN" was the key to get it to work. Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can use "SELF[index]" in a predicate to access specific elements of the sub-array.
The following predicate finds all sub-arrays where the first element is in the
specified range:

```
float lowValue = 1.5;
float hiValue = 2.5;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[0] > %f AND SELF[0] < %f", lowValue, hiValue];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If you want to find the sub-arrays that contain *any* number in the specified range, use

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF BETWEEN %@", @[@(lowValue), @(hiValue)]];
```